# Fill ViewBox completely with part of image area determined by Image.Clip

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a large image I want to use within an Windows Phone 8.1 app. For the purpose of my application I want to show only a certain part of the image and want to fill the complete ViewBox with that specific part.

I can easily get the specific part of the Image by using Image.Clip. However until now I have been unable to get the ViewBox filled with only the part determined by Image.Clip.
I use the following XAML.

```
     <Pivot>
        <PivotItem Margin="10">
            <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both">
                <Image Source="http://image.png"
                       Stretch="None">
                    <Image.Clip>
                         <RectangleGeometry Rect="500,100,600,700"/>
                    </Image.Clip>
                </Image>
            </Viewbox>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

I've tried various combinations of Stretch settings on both the Image and the ViewBox. I'also experimented with ScaleTransforms but until now no luck.

So my question is is what I want to do possible from within XAML and if so which combination of XAML code should I use?

Comment: try doing stretch uniform. <Image Source="http://image.png"
                       Stretch="Uniform">

Comment: Hi Rohit, Yes tried that in various combinations. But it gave not the results I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fill a fixed size Rectangle with a translated ImageBrush like this:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both">
    <Rectangle Width="600" Height="700">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="http://image.png"
                        Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top">
                <ImageBrush.Transform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-500" Y="-100"/>
                </ImageBrush.Transform>
            </ImageBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Hi Clemens, Tried your suggestion and it worked! Thanks my problem is solved now.